# how to set scroll bar for tab host

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-tabhost

i want to set scroll bar in tab host.in tab there is five tab but i want to display only three
tab at a time and how to make scrollbar for that so tab can be scroll for more tab...please provide me some solution.......

this is m xml file.....

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layTab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbars="none" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </TabWidget>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                    android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Home_feed"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                    android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                    android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment4"
                    android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment5"
                    android:name="info.tech.slidermenu.Upcoming_tennise_match"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is class file....

```
public void tabselect() {
    TabHost tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tab.setup();
    tab.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.fragment1);
    spec.setIndicator("Feed");

    tab.addTab(spec);
    spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.fragment2);
    spec.setIndicator("tennis");
    tab.addTab(spec);

    spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.fragment3);
    spec.setIndicator("boxing");
    tab.addTab(spec);

    spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.fragment4);
    spec.setIndicator("cricket");
    tab.addTab(spec);

    spec = tab.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.fragment5);
    spec.setIndicator("base ball");
    tab.addTab(spec);

    tab.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

screen shot....

[image]

Comment: If you haven't gone far with your code. I would suggest using View Pager with PageStrip. They provide scroll by flipping the screen plus it uses fragments as well and TabHost is deprecated too. http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/how-to-use-the-pagertabstrip-and-the-pagertitlestrip/ You would definitely get many more examples ob PageStrip. Just google. :)

Comment: can you help me how to use it with this code..

Comment: Please implement a fragmentTab, the code you are using will not feel so good to work with once you advance. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678093/Fragments-Creating-a-Tabbed-Android-User-Interface with fragments you dont have to worry about the screen sizes and your tab will auto adjust.

Comment: You appear to have a `HorizontalScrollView` wrapped around the `TabWidget`, which IIRC is the typical recipe for scrolling tabs using `TabHost`. Please explain **completely and precisely** what your problem is.

Comment: @CommonsWare tab are not visible at all.....only fragment content is visible...if i don't use horizontalscrollview ...all tabs are visible..

Answer (score 1):

You're already using a `HorizontalScrollView` for the `TabWidget`, so this is the correct way. If you're not able to scrool despite doing is this way, probably you're having a layout problem.

You didn't detail if you're using a custom layout for your `TabWidget`, but if not, this would be a good approach to achieve what you want, since there's not a method to say "I just want to show 3 tabs at a time".

Simply define a new layout for your tabs so the three together fit the screen's width, the rest will be reachable by scrolling.

**---- EDIT ----**

I see pretty much `LinearLayout`s in your code. Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TabContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="99"
            android:orientation="vertical">
  <TabHost
            android:id="@+android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TabLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
      <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
      </HorizontalScrollView>
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```